# Companion Matrix of first degree monomial $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, companion-matrices

What is the Companion matrix of $x$? Is it $[0]$ or $[1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition that the characteristic polynomial of the companion matrix is equal to the original polynomial, you have $C(p) = [0]$ if $p(x)=x$.